# Add the installation prefix of "Qt5OpenCV" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "Qt5OpenCV_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files

Tags: opencv, qt5

It is normal when qt5 and opencv are running separately.

Now I want to use OpenCV in Qt5, When building, I got the following error, I can't find relevant solutions online
.

```
CMake Error at /opt/Qt5.13.0/5.13.0/gcc_64/lib/cmake/Qt5/Qt5Config.cmake:28 (find_package):

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5OpenCV" with
  any of the following names:

    Qt5OpenCVConfig.cmake
    qt5opencv-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Qt5OpenCV" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "Qt5OpenCV_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "Qt5OpenCV" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
```

This is the compilation command of my opencv.

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D WITH_QT=ON -D WITH_GTK=ON ../opencv-4.7.0
make && make install
```

My CMakeLists.txt

```
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "/opt/Qt5.13.0/5.13.0/gcc_64/")

#I think this directory should be included, but I don't know where it is.
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "Qt5OpenCV") 

find_package(Qt5
    COMPONENTS
    Core
    Quick
    OpenCV
    REQUIRED)

include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} "src/main.cpp" "qml/qml.qrc")

link_directories(${OpenCV_LIBRARY_DIRS})

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
    PRIVATE
    Qt5::Core
    Qt5::Quick
    ${OpenCV_LIBS}
    )
```

My system is Ubuntu22.10

I hope everything is normal.

Comment: In addition, cmake build information ` GUI: QT5 - QT: YES (ver 5.15.6)  ` Try to modify CMakeLists.txt `set (CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ${Qt5OpenCV_DIR}) `, it still doesn't work. Is there a problem with my qt installation method?

Comment: your operating system has the necessary installations ? please install pre-requested libraries before installing opencv